# Enabling second UART in U-Boot

Tags: embedded-linux, uart, boot, u-boot

I am working on a project with SAMA5D3-xplained board with CortexA5 processor and embedded Linux. I would like to send and receive some data via UART during U-Boot is running and before a kernel is loaded to the RAM. I have no idea what I should do. Should I add the second UART to U-Boot device tree source file? Should I change something in a board configuration file? Do you have any ideas on what steps I should take to achieve my goal? Thank you in advance for any help.

**EDIT**
I would like to use UART from U-Boot C code, not from U-Boot commands. I need to communicate with one of a peripheral device before the kernel is loaded to the RAM.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using the upstream U-Boot from https://source.denx.de/u-boot/u-boot.git.

The device-tree arch/arm/dts/at91-sama5d3_xplained.dts already contains the definitions for six different uarts called serial0 - serial5. serial0 is set in the /chosen node as the standard serial connection. You should be able to see all six devices with the 'dm tree' command.

The currently used UART can be switched by setting the stdin and stdout environment variables.

If you do not want to switch these variables, because you still want output on the default UART you will have to access the device driver. Unfortunately drivers/serial/serial-uclass.c does not yet export functions for this. But _serial_putc(), __serial_getc(), and __serial_tstc() should give you an idea how this is done.